# Edit an argument with a loop

Tags: c#, iteration

I am attempting to alter a series of 4 .bat files. When I run the program, it prompts me for an input and then writes it to the .bat file.

I took the code below from the microsoft documentation on File.Openwrite, then added some variables to point to the files.

As opposed to copy/pasting the code that actually writes the text, I put a for loop around it with the intent of altering the argument so that the File.OpenWrite piece will look to a different variable (and so a different path/directory) during each iteration. I confirmed that the loop works (if I enter one of the path# variables it will iterate through and write to that file 4 times) and that File.OpenWrite is seeing the correct text each iteration. My only guess is that it is looking at the 'path#' argument literally and not seeing it as a variable. Can someone help me understand how I can alter this argument through iteration?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string path0 = path + @"\down_fa.bat";
        string path1 = path + @"\down_ng.bat";
        string path2 = path + @"\down_os.bat";
        string path3 = path + @"\down_sp.bat";
        string portinput = Console.ReadLine();
        string dotbatinput = "DDL -p" + portinput;

        // Open the stream and write to it. 

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("path" + i))
            {
                Byte[] info =
                    new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(dotbatinput);

                // Add some information to the file.
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your guess is correct

Comment: Just put all the paths in an array and loop through that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.OpenWrite("path" + 0) != File.OpenWrite(path0)
```

The left side opens a stream to a file called "path0" which you will find in the `bin\Debug` directory of your project and the right example writes a file at the location specified in the string `path0`. The same of course applies to the other numbers. A possible solution would be to use an array or a list:

```
string[] paths = new string[4].Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).ToArray();
string[0] += ...;
string[1] += ...;
string[2] += ...;
string[3] += ...;

foreach (string path in paths)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to a variable declared in your code using a string and concatenating a number. In this way you pass a literal string to the OpenWrite method not the content of the variable with the name equals to your string.

A simpler approach is to add every batch file to a list of strings and then loop over that list writing the content required

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
List<string> batFiles = new List<string>();
batFiles.Add(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "down_fa.bat"));
batFiles.Add(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "down_ng.bat"));
batFiles.Add(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "down_os.bat"));
batFiles.Add(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "down_sp.bat"));
string portinput = Console.ReadLine();
string dotbatinput = "DDL -p" + portinput;

foreach(string batFile in batFiles)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(batFile))
    {
     -----
    }
}
```